# TypeScript enum values as typed array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Looking to type the possible values in an array as those of an enum:

```
enum MyEnum {
    FirstRole = "FIRST",
    SecondRole = "SECOND"
}

type MyType {
   roles: MyEnum[] // I want to enforce this array to only strings of FIRST or SECOND as depicted in the enum i.e. ["FIRST", "SECOND"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare array using custom type like below:

```
type Role =  "First" | "Second";
let roles: Array<Role> = [ "First"];
```

The roles would allow only First or Second strings.

Comment: The point of an enum is to be able to reference a value without having to use it as a literal. Using this method we are using string literals, which means you have to update the `type Role` every time the enum changes, which defeats the purpose of using it. It seems typescript doesn't support this at all.

Comment: You don't have to use both enum and role type. If you need to you can use it like below:
`enum roleType { 
    "First",
    "Second"
};

type Role = roleType.First | roleType.Second;
let roles: Array<Role> = [roleType.First];`

Answer (score 0):

Simply like this

```
    enum MyEnum {
        FirstRole = 'FIRST',
        SecondRole = 'SECOND',
    }
    type role = 'FIRST' | 'SECOND';
    const role: MyEnum[] | role[] = [MyEnum.FirstRole, 'FIRST'];
```